# mkfs ext2 ignore number-of-inodes

Tags: filesystems, mkfs, ext2

I want to make ext2 file system. I want to set "[number-of-inodes](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext2)" option to some number. I tried several values:

- if *-N 99000* then Inode count: 99552
- if *-N 3500* then Inode count:
  3904
- if *-N 500* then Inode count: 976

But always my value is **not the same**. Why?

I call mkfs this way

```
sudo mkfs -q -t ext2 -F /dev/sda2 -b 4096 -N 99000 -O none,sparse_super,large_file,filetype
```

I check results this way

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
tune2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              99552
Block count:              1973720
Reserved block count:     98686
Overhead clusters:        6362
Free blocks:              1967353
Free inodes:              99541
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         1632
Inode blocks per group:   102
Filesystem created:       Thu Apr  6 20:00:45 2023
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Thu Apr  6 20:01:49 2023
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Apr  6 20:00:45 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      61ff1bad-c6c8-409f-b334-f277fb29df54
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you creating such an archaic filesystem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number hasn't been ignored, it's been rounded up.  It looks like space for inodes are allocated in groups.  See in your output:

```
Inodes per group:         1632
```

When you request 99,000 inodes, that's not divisible by 1,632.  So to ensure that you get the number of inodes you requested, the number has been rounded up to 99,552 which is divisible by 1,632.

It looks like this limit might be somehow derived from the number of [block groups](https://wiki.osdev.org/Ext2#What_is_a_Block_Group.3F), where the number of inodes in each group is uniform across all block groups.  My guess is that the number of inodes per block group is calculated as the number of inodes requested divided by the number of block groups and then rounded up to a whole number.  See [Ext2 on OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Ext2)

> #### What is a Block Group? Blocks, along with inodes, are divided up into "block groups." These are nothing more than contiguous groups of
>
> blocks.
>
> Each block group reserves a few of its blocks for special purposes
> such as:
>
> - ...
> - A table of inode structures that belong to the group
> - ..